# What is the difference in notation for Ln(z) vs. ln(z)

Tags: complex-numbers

We are learning about the principal vs. non-principal values of the natural logarithm. There are 2 problems:

1. $\ln(-7)$
2. $\operatorname{Ln}(-7)$

I solved $\ln(-7)$ for:
$$=\ln|-7|+i\pi+2\pi k$$

Is the difference in notation for the other problem *really* just removing the $2\pi k$? Or maybe it would be better if I define the argument like $-\pi<\theta<\pi$?

Comment: Which branches are these, i.e., what are your definitions of $\ln$ and $\operatorname{Ln}$?

Comment: As a multivalue function, $\ln{z}$ has, as you mentioned has the periodic $2\pi k$.  the $Ln{z}$ is the principal branch.

Comment: @Travis So there isn't a standard range then? Should I explicitly write that $-\pi<\theta<\pi$ ?

Comment: There's no "canonical" choice for the branch cut of logarithm. I'd say that choosing a branch to take values in $(-\pi, \pi]$ is most common, but this is not universal, and not the right choice for all situations. For example, when using contour integration to evaluate certain real integrals involving the logarithm over $[0, \infty)$, choosing the branch with values in $[0, 2\pi)$ is easiest.

Comment: I see, I see. Ok. Good to know, that's all I was wondering. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It is a convention in complex analysis to denote the principle branch of a multivalued function by capitalizing the first letter.

In this case, $\operatorname{Ln}(z) = \operatorname{Ln}|z|+i \operatorname{Arg}(z)$

As for $\operatorname{Ln}$, $\operatorname{Arg}$ is the principle branch of the the argument function, taking values in $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: I guess my question was worded ambiguously. I simply want to know if the difference between the final answers for both problems is just writing the $2\pi k$ or not.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: yes it is....that is it

Comment: Oh wow....ok so I guess I have the concept right, I'm just wondering about the notation for the final answers. Do I assume that everyone knows that $Ln$ is defined in $(-\pi,\pi]$ or does that part also need to be written?

Comment: Assume that my professor is super formal....lol

Comment: It is convention. If you are using it numerous times, and are afraid of ambiguities, you could define it yourself the first time it is used.

Comment: Thanks @MathMajor that's basically what I was wondering.