# How to distinguish the notation of inverse trigonometric relations from inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry

**1st way:**

One way to differentiate them would be the [following](https://www.sparknotes.com/math/trigonometry/trigonometricequations/section3/#:%7E:text=The%20inverse%20functions%20appear%20as,relations%20into%20the%20inverse%20functions.):

> The symbols for the inverse functions differ from the symbols for the
> inverse relations: the names of the functions are capitalized. The
> inverse functions appear as follows: Arcsine, Arccosine, Arctangent,
> Arccosecant, Arcsecant, and Arccotangent

So, relations are written non-capitalized ($\arcsin(x)$), and functions are written capitalized ($\text{Arcsin(x)}$).

**2nd way:**

Another way of writing the inverse trig relations/functions is like this: $\sin^{-1}(x)$. How can we differentiate between inverse trig relations and functions if it is written in this way? In other words, if I find $\sin^{-1}(x)$ written down on a piece of paper, what will I interpret it as: a function or a relation?

**Questions:**

1. How can I differentiate $\sin^{-1}(x)$ as a function and $\sin^{-1}(x)$ as a relation?
2. If I find $\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$ written down on a piece of paper, will I write $\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})=30^{\circ}$ or $\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})=150^{\circ}$?

Comment: Both is fine, and each has advantages.

Comment: 1. Context. 2. While IMO Arcsin clearly indicates the principal angle, I generally read arcsin too as the principal angle anyway (i.e., as a function rather than a relation). It would be a bad idea to assume that arcsin is automatically a relation, unless the text explicitly distinguishes between Arcsin and arcsin. 3. The same issue crops up in complex analysis for log vs. Log (ln vs. Ln).

Comment: [What is the difference in notation for Ln(z) vs. ln(z)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1652675/21813)

Comment: @ryang Hmmm. I edited the question slightly.

Comment: @ryang I see. What would you say about Q1?

Comment: For Q2, I don't think that $\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$ is ever straight-up interpreted as $150^{\circ}.$ If I'd like to list the entire collection of possibilites, I'd just say that 
$x$ is such that $\sin x=0.5$ or that $x\in\{x\vert\sin x=0.5 \}.$ I understand $150^{\circ}$ to be $\pi-\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}).$ In any case, I think sin$^{-1}$ is just as distinct (or not effectively distinct, haha) from Sin$^{-1}$ as arcsin is from Arcsin.

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/math/trigonometry/how-to-distinguish-between-trigonometry-functions-and-relations-186918

Comment: As a (very) minor criticism of the posting, it is a bad idea to use the verb *differentiate* here.  In the Pre-Calculus world, you wouldn't have any way of knowing that the verb *differentiate* usually refers to taking derivatives (in Calculus).  A synonym would be the verb *distinguish*.  When I first read your posting, the verb *differentiate* threw me.  It wasn't until I completed the posting and noticed that there was no Real-Analysis tag that I was able to reverse engineer what you intended by the verb *differentiate*.